# pgsql2shp: create shapefile from empty table, but with known attributes (dbf)

Tags: postgis, pgsql2shp

I was trying to generate shapefile from postgis tables using `pgsql2shp`. Everything is fine except for table with no rows.

When trying to create shapefile from an empty table, an error occurs:

`Could not determine table metadata (empty table)`

I checked the [source code of `pgsql2shp`](https://github.com/postgis/postgis/blob/05f569e0aed4d7f05f9f3a9d6a6af8a7e5578a0a/loader/pgsql2shp-core.c#L928) in git and it appears that the error is explicitly thrown without checking any of the options provided.

I was expecting that an empty shapefile with a DBF schema the same as the table schema would be generated. Is there a way to get this behavior?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. Empty tables will lead to the `Could not determine table metadata (empty table)` and no shp file is created as expected. Which options were you expecting to override this?

Comment: @JohnBarça: Well I want an empty table to produce empty shapefile. Thats all.

Comment: The following will produce an empty shp file: pgsql2shp -f 'yourshape.shp' db "SELECT ST_GeomFromEWKT('POLYGON EMPTY')"; I could not get this to work with a case statement to determine dynamically whether table has geometies or not, but it would be easy enough to create a bash script (or similar) to do.

Comment: @JohnBarça: That will not work because I want an empty shapefile with dbf schema same as the table schema.

Comment: Perhaps you could put that information in the question :D.

Comment: @JohnBarça: I understand what made you unclear. Added that. Thanks.

Comment: Had the same problem with 50+ tables. My solution was to create the 'empty' tables in pg with limit 1 instead of limit 0. After export with pgsql2shp a Python script truncated the tables.